# Whats the difference between these two classes

Tags: python, class, object-oriented-analysis

Hi I have a question about these two class's , •    The bus (i.e., what values does it need to store and what actions can it take)
•   The command (i.e., what type of command has been issued to what bus and what values) I'm confused as to what the difference would be, the bus class will have the function where it moves it self. But then what is the command class for? I need to use to different classes for this one has been called bus and other command.

Guidlines---
You are running a bus company with four buses.  These buses will move around based on commands provided from keyboard input.  To move a bus, you will issue a command from the keyboard with the bus identification, direction, and number of spaces to move.  For example:
B W 3
Would move Bus “B” three spaces to the West.  All buses will start at the bus station at coordinates (0,0).  A “N”orth command would increment the y-coordinate; “S”outh decrement the y-coordinate.  A “E”ast command increments the x-coordinate and a “W”est command decrements the x-coordinate.
You will also accept commands to pick up and drop off people:
D P 5
A D 2

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that we cannot see your code?

Comment: yes I don't have any code, because I don't know what the difference between each class would be

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @KidProg. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask].

Comment: If there's no code for these classes then the only difference is their name.

Comment: would my question be more clear if I post the project guidelines?

Comment: Maybe. On the other hand, why don't you ask the person who gave you the guidelines if they are unclear?

Comment: Command and Bus were probably built for this project. Nobody would know about it except for your professor.

Comment: he won't really tell us, but this program is a bus program that moves a bus by typing like east or west. the bus class will have that info in It. I'm just confuses as in what the command class would then have

Comment: What is "the bus"? KidProg the problem with this question is the fact that you can't see why we have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. You haven't provided us any info on what the command is or what the bus is but you want us to tell the difference?

Comment: I am very sorry this is my first time on here let me post some more details

Comment: My first question was how many bits wide is the bus? Then I realized...

Answer (score 0):

In trying to understand your question, I see a bus class also known as a bus object.

It is just like a physical bus with attributes like:

License plate number
Capacity

And whatever other attributes make up that bus.

The command class if I am reading correctly is a class that can be inherited by bus, but it could also be inherited by other objects. If you had a bus object and a car object, they both have a license plate.

If a bus and a car had some different attributes, they would be different.

They could both inherit the command class however, and if the command class were to have a go function, they would both be able to go.

Abstraction and polymorphism can be tricky, but it is key to object oriented programming.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Probably, whatever sort of design you use, a `Bus` shouldn't inherit from `Command`, or vice versa.

Comment: ^ I agree. A `command` is probably more of a class that keeps track of bus locations and movements and wouldn't have anything to do with the Bus class in terms of inheritance.

Comment: Interesting. If that is how you feel. Whether it is location or go, it would have to be inherited in order to be used. The object needs to know it can do something.

Comment: @SynchroDynamic no, it *wouldn't* have to be inherit. As a general rule, inheritence implies an "is-a" relationship. A bus is a command? A command is a bus? A bus can *take* commands. Or a command *acts on* buses. There is no "is-a" relationship between a bus and command.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to get so upset. I must be reading the question differently. The way I am reading it is that the command class is a component class. If it is not then my apologize. The question is pretty open ended.

Comment: I'm not getting angry, I'm adding italics for emphasis. I suppose, I would UPPERCASE if I were yelling and angry :). But I'm not sure what you mean by component class. But in general, you should favor object composition over inheritance, especially if there is no logical "is-a" relationship between the entities you are modelling.

Comment: Its been a while since i have been in school and held to a specific word to define what I mean. I called it inheritance. It is composition for those still in school. I just call all of that inheritance. my bad. you said, "is-a" i meant has-a. good catch on the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Still confusing, but I'll give it a shot. If these are the only two classes in your program I think the division is pretty clear.

The `Bus` will be a `class` that holds information about the bus. It will have member `variables` that represent its position on the "map" (x,y) with a move function that will update these member variables. So when you call `busname.move(variables)` it will move like you want it to and update its position. Additionally it seems like it would have a `variable` representing how many people are on board.

The `command` class is something else entirely, it would be the main control for your program. It would have instances of the `bus` class as its members (A,B,C,D) and it would interpret commands from the keyboard to determine what command to issue to what `bus`. For example, if you type A W 3 on the keyboard how is bus A ever supposed to know to move to the west three spaces? Because the command class will take the keyboard input and call `A.move(-3, 0)` or something like that to update its position.

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow thanks, now if you could, I know I'm assigning a lot here. could u provide an example with code?

Comment: Hey KidProg, I'll let someone else edit my answer for that if they desire -- I write object-oriented code in C++, not Python, so I wouldn't be of much use anyway.